# SSRS charts are not displaying

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created line graphs in my SSRS reports. When I put the reports on server and called the reports on my page using MHTML data stream of SSRS, the data is appearing in report but the line graph is not showing. Icon of image not found us appearing. Please help me on this.

Comment: You need to provide more info or this question will probably get votes to be closed.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Like Alan already said, you need to provide more information. How does your dataset look? A minimal sample would be good. Also information about your chart. What are the values, how does the cathegory look? Then we can help you.